# Angular 4 Http interceptor ,, i am geting an error at the time of "ng serve"

Tags: angular, http, interceptor

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or
>   lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 69:19 in the
>   original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in
>   /src/app/app.module.ts

**HttpService.js**

```typescript
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {
   constructor(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
    let token = localStorage.user_token; // your custom token getter function here
    options.headers.set('token', `${token}`);
    super(backend, options);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    let token =  localStorage.user_token;
    if (typeof url === 'string') { // meaning we have to add the token to the options, not in url
      if (!options) {
        // let's make option object
        options = {headers: new Headers()};
      }
      options.headers.set('token', `${token}`);
    } else {
      // we have to add the token to the url object
      url.headers.set('token', `${token}`);
    }
    return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
  }

  private catchAuthError(self: HttpService) {
    // we have to pass HttpService's own instance here as `self`
    return (res: Response) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
        // if not authenticated
        console.log(res);
      }
      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }
}
```

**app.module.js**

```typescript
providers: [
    {
      provide: HttpService,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
        return new HttpService(backend, options);
      },
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    },
    UserService,CookieService,ProductService,ConfirmationService,AuthGaurdService,

  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error states **Consider replacing lambda with a reference to an exported function** like:

```typescript
export function httpServiceFactory(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new HttpService(backend, options);
}
```

now your provider should look like:

```typescript
{
  provide: HttpService,
  useFactory: httpServiceFactory,
  deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
},
```

Comment: thnaks yurzui , now that error gone but got new error

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property '_backend' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property '_backend' of undefined
    at Http (http.es5.js:1892)
    at HttpService (http-service.service.ts:13)
    at _callFactory (core.es5.js:9548)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.es5.js:9487)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9469)
    at _createClass (core.es5.js:9512)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.es5.js:9484)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9469)
    at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@ang

Comment: Did you import HttpModule in your AppModule?

Comment: yes i have import

import {Http, HttpModule , RequestOptions, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';

but error because of this 

constructor(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions)

Comment: Can you check this https://plnkr.co/edit/HIu5Cc7ES61UEICJ944z?p=preview

Comment: I meant `imports` array within NgModule `imports: [HttpModule]`

Comment: imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpModule,

Comment: Please reproduce the error in plunker or in minimal github repo

Comment: Thanks @yurzui  , now its working i have miss httpServiceFactory code  , its working fine thanks lot

Comment: Hello @yurzui , i have one more problem , i want to use cookie insted of localStorage.user_token , please help me